# How to check Auth::user() -> roles() if null in Blad

Tags: javascript

I've got the following line in my Javascript

```
    let roles =  {!! Auth::user()->roles()->get()  !!};
```

Now if i'm not authenticated this line throws an error

```
Call to a member function roles() on null (View: D:\data\Project\resources\views\booking.blade.php)
```

although i just want to be redirected to the /login page!

Can anybody tell me how to do this? It's no problem to do it in the controller but on the page itself i tried Blade command like

```
@if (!empty(Auth::user()))
```

...
@endif

but without success!

Comment: I do upvote as I see someone down-voted, why down-vote?  :-(

Comment: really? think nobody downvoted your answer? it was a good one, thx man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
let roles =  {!! Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->roles()->get() : ''  !!};
```